# ERROR: use callback in setstate when referencing the previous state

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error on the last line of code:

**use callback in setstate when referencing the previous state**

```
likeClick = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
e.stopPropagation();
const { content, comment } = this.props;
const { isLiked, isWaiting } = this.state;

if (isWaiting) {
  return;
}
if (content !== null) {
  if (isLiked) {
    this.contentActions.unlikeContent(
      content.id,
      this.onUnlikeContentCallback,
    );
  } else {
    this.xApiService.sendContentLikedStatement(content);
    this.contentActions.likeContent(content.id, this.onLikeContentCallback);
  }
}
this.setState({ ...this.state, isWaiting: true })
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `updater` version of `setState`

```
this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, isWaiting: true }))
```

`this` is mutable, you can't rely on it to spread the old state, the updater version of `setState` provides you a snapshot of your state which won't change even the actual state is beeing changed somewhere else.